# How can I make a unified field relatable to fields in other tables?

Tags: ms-access, union

I have two tables, each with a primary field called 'Unit', along with other fields pertaining to associated data. While the associated data pertaining to the Unit of each field is different (reflecting different survey methods), Units themselves are defined in the same way.

What I need to do is (1) group all Units from both tables into a single field, while also (2) be able to use that field in a relationship. I also (3) need this unified field to be updated automatically as new Units are added to their respective tables.

I've set up a union query to unify the two kinds of Units, which satisfies my 1st and 3rd requirements, but queries cannot be used in relationships. Is there a way to convert the unified data in the union query to a table in a way that ensures it is automatically updated? Make Table queries are fine for creating the table initially, but are not so good for keeping the information up to date (running it again, which deletes and re-creates the table, requires the table to not be in any relationships in order for deleting to occur). Moreover, an Append query would not update records that are already in the table, but merely add new records, which is not sufficient for this project.

I could also write some VBA to copy a string into another unified field in another table when this information is being input via a form, but I would prefer to have a solution at the table level and not be dependent on forms for data entry. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I also tried the solution presented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208870) and [here](http://thedbguy.blog.com/2013/11/update-query-with-append/), but I receive the cryptic error message "Operation must use an updateable query". My permissions are fine, and I'm at a loss.

Comment: Still thinking through your issue, but as for the error in your edit, datasources are only updateable when all underlying tables are related by one-to-one relationships, and are not being used in a union query (unions are considered aggregations, and because of aggregated data Access cannot identify the precise row that needs to be updated in the underlying tables). http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: Ah, thanks for that explanation, and for linking to that informative article.

Comment: When I drag the unified field from the union query over to the target field, referential integrity options are greyed out, and no relationship type is defined (even 'indeterminate'). This probably has to do with the fact that there is no key set in the query, right?